# Rails 4 + Nginx - serve font via CloudFront won't load cause by CORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I've website at http://revoniaga.com which is run RoR but the font won't load where it said "blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy". It cause by Amazon CloudFront. I've try everything but still same result.

First, I put my font assets under /app/assets/font

then in my css (vendor/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome.css), I use something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
 //and so on for other font format
}
```

At my /etc/nginx/sites-available/revoniaga_production, I put

```
location ~* \.(eot|otf|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Then when I curl:

```
curl -I https://d3bkb7gt2ds4m6.cloudfront.net/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
```

It said

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 168
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 09:34:29 GMT
Age: 242
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 404e3b476748051f3f9bc690b72173b4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 3yUNjkFQHC83FlbEwVMBSddpQND_4GbXauyeTtDyKawS6GzftUwXRA==
```

I'm also restarting my server "service nginx restart" but still nothing happen

Here is my CloudFront which is the default setting

[image]

Everything work fine in my dev env

I couldn't figure why this happening. Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by clean install the server, upgrade ruby to 2.2.1 plus.. looks like the issue come from the server itself. my setting before was fine..